# MongoDB revert property to default value after time elapse

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a situation where I need to set a MongoDB property back to 0 (its default value) inside of a User object.

For example, statusCode is set to 1 to signify account is under review, if it is not set to another value after 5 minutes it must be set back to its original value 0.

I am using these as statusCodes for a User object, 1 means the account is under review by an Administrator and prevents other admins from loading the same object.

However if for some reason the admin does not complete the review process I do not want the value left at 1 because then the object will not be loaded to complete the review process.

In my code below, I am setting the value to 1 in my Express route but not sure where to apply this logic to revert the value to 0 if it not set to another value such as 2, 3, 4, etc... **after 5 minutes**

Thank you!

```
router.get(`/api/verify`, auth, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      idVerified: false,
      verificationStatus: 0,
    }).sort({
      createdAt: 1,
    })

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .send({ error: "No users to verify, check back soon!" })
    }

     // set to 1 signifying account is under review
    await user.updateOne({ verificationStatus: 1 })

    s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrl(
      "getObject",
      {
        Bucket: "mapspot-verification",
        Key: user.idImageKey,
      },
      (err, url) => res.send({ user, url })
    )
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
  }
})
```

Comment: Wait... how will this logic be executed post 5 minutes time that you are talking about? Are you planning to write a cron job or something?

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I actually did not know what a Cron Job is until now, I see it is for scheduling tasks, which sounds like the right path...